# Animación en Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estoy realizando una aplicación en tiempo real con localizaciones de incidencias y estoy buscando la manera de realizar animaciones en el mapa. Cada vez que entra una nueva localización que el mapa se desplace lentamente hasta dicha localización y una vez el mapa centrado haga un zoom de manera pausada y lenta.

La aplicación la estoy desarrollando con google maps como servidor de mapas, Angular 2 aunque estoy metiendo Javascript puro para manipular la API de google maps, de backend Node js y MongoDB de Base de Datos. De tal manera que la incidencia llega a Node que la almacena en MongoDB y la manda por websocket a Angular 2 que manipula la api de google maps.

No encuentro la manera de hacer estas animación. ¿Alguna idea? ¿Quizá se puede mezclar google maps con WebGL?

Cualquier apunte sera bien recibido! Gracias!!!

Comment: Da algunos detalles más sobre en que entorno estas trabajando. Puedo entender que es HTML5, pero también puede ser Android, iOS...
Usas JQuery? Algún otro framework? Javascript puro?

Intenta hacer la pregunta algo más detallada y seguro podemos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Tienes razón. He actualizado la pregunta dando más detalles. Gracias!